# json to C# objects

Tags: c#, json

I receive a JSON string from a external system and I want to turn in to C# objects. The problem is that the "CAR" objects are unique in the string and I do not know how many there is (0 to many).

Now, It doesn't make sense to hardcode classes for each "CAR" like class: CAR1, class: CAR2 and so on. I tried to create a general CAR class and was thinking I could loop throu the JSON and create CAR objects.

The problem is that I cant't identify and find each CAR dynamically.I find the attributes and values for "CAR1" by hardcode "CAR1".
I would like to find a solution like:

```
foreach(item.key where key starts with "CAR")
```

Tried the following:

```
var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsondata, expConverter);
dynamic json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsondata);
            foreach (var itm in obj)
            {
               string s = itm.Key;
               if(s.StartsWith("CAR"))
                {
                   CarObj = new Car();
                   CarObj.HP = json.CAR1[0].HORSEPOWER[0];
                   CarObj.COLOR = json.CAR1[0].COLOR[0];
                  // Would like to use something like
                  //  CarObj.HP = json.**item.key**[0].HORSEPOWER[0];

                }
            }
```

---

```
{
    "CAR1": [{
        "HORSEPOWER": ["180", "int", "Hp"],
        "COLOR": ["GREEN", "string", "COLOR"]
    }],
    "CAR2": [{
        "HORSEPOWER": ["200", "int", "Hp"],
        "COLOR": ["BlUE", "string", "COLOR"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the JSON using another code or is it something that you can't control?

Comment: your casting ````array```` to ````dynamic````.try with ````list<dynamic>```` instead of  ````dynamic````

Comment: I can't contol the incoming json string. Just want to create objects of its content .

Comment: Ok,thank's jagadeesh ! , will try the List option. But still can't see how that would help me find each "CAR" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not forced to use `dynamic` right away. First use the strongly-typed APIs to find the right portion of the JSON, then switch to dynamic:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var element in obj)
{
    if (element.Key.StartsWith("CAR"))
    {
        dynamic value = element.Value;

        var carObj = new Car();
        carObj.HP = value[0].HORSEPOWER[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, perfect solution !!

Comment: @TStefan if an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Where/how do I mark it solved ? stupid question but Im new to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize as `Dictionary<string,List<CarDetails>>`

```
public class CarDetails
{
    public List<string> HORSEPOWER { get; set; }

    public List<string> COLOR { get; set; }
}
```

and then iterate the dictionary to get the results.